# decoding via number combinations algorithm in python 3

Tags: algorithm

ok so here is the problem.

let's say:

```
1 means Bob
2 means Jerry
3 means Tom
4 means Henry
```

any summation combination of two of aforementioned numbers is a status/ mood type which is how the program will be encoded:

```
7 (4+3) means Angry
5 (3+2) menas Sad
3 (2+1) means Mad
4 (3+1) means Happy
and so on...
```

how may i create a decode function such that it accepts one of the added (encoded) values, such as 7, 5, 3, 4, etc and figures out the combination and return the names of the people representing the two numbers that constitue the combination. take note that one number cannot be repeated to get mood result, meaning 4 has to be 3+1 and may not be 2+2. so we can assume for this example, that there is only one possible combination for each status/ mood code. now the problem is, how do you implement such code in python 3? what would be the algorithm or logic for such a problem. how do you seek or check for combination of two numbers? i'm thinking i should just run a loop that keeps on adding two numbers at a time until the result matches with the status/ mood code. will that work? BUT THIS METHOD WILL SOON BECOME OBSOLETE IF THE NUMBER OF COMBINATIONS IS INCREASED (as in adding 4 numbers together instead of 2). doing it this way will take up a lot of time and will possibly be inefficient.

i apologize, i know this questions is extremely confusing but please bear with me.
let's try and work something out.

Comment: What is a number is a combination of more than 1 set of numbers ?
9 = 5+3+1 , 9 = 2+7 , 9 = 8 + 1 , 9 = 5+4 ?

Comment: for now, let's keep it to only 2 numbers

Comment: summation between 1-4

Comment: so the highest combination for this question would be 7 (3+4)

Comment: just to keep things simple...

Comment: Your system will not give a unique pair of people for a given "mood" number. For instance, if you have 5 people, a mood value of 5 would correspond to people 1,4 and 2,3

Comment: @kuroi neko that's why i limit it to 1-4 for now

Comment: For the sake of other people wanting to index unordered pairs who could stumble on this page, I suggest you read my answer and see if it fits your problem better than using a binary approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use Binary

If you want to have sums that are unique, then assign each possible "Person" a number that's a power of 2. The sum of any combination of these numbers will uniquely identify which numbers were used in the sum.

1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...

Rather than offer a detailed proof of correctness, I offer an intuitive argument about this: any number can be represented in base 2, and it is always a sum of exactly one combination of powers of 2.

This solution may not be optimal. It has realistic limitations (32 or 64 different "person" identifiers, unless you use some sort of BigInt), but depending on your needs, it might work. Having the smallest possible values, binary is better than any other radix though.

### Example

*(Edited)*

Here's a quick snippet that demonstrates how you could decode the sum. The returned values are the exponents of the powers of 2. `count_persons` could be arbitrarily large, as could the range of `n` iterated over (just as a quick example).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

count_persons = 64

for n in range(20,30):
    matches = list(filter(lambda i: (n>>i) & 0x1, range(1,count_persons)))
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(n,matches))
```

Output:

```
20: [2, 4]
21: [2, 4]
22: [1, 2, 4]
23: [1, 2, 4]
24: [3, 4]
25: [3, 4]
26: [1, 3, 4]
27: [1, 3, 4]
28: [2, 3, 4]
29: [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: +1. This solution is easily generalizable, and it's easy to implement, and it's fast.

Comment: Yes, but it will work for at most 64 people unless you use big numbers. I suspect you can compress the coding a bit more

Comment: i understand, but how would you check something like that? for instance that two numbers added make the other number?

Comment: Python has big integers, though.

Comment: @mojo you're right, but I think there are other limiting factors. Using big numbers in this context could be rather cumbersome.

Comment: @kuroineko Since we don't really have any context, it's hard to know how useful this solution would be. It's functionally correct, at least.

Comment: @mojo see my answer. I can go into further details on how I did the coding, but as often here on SO, the OP seems to have grabbed his quick answer and scampered off, so it might not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

See a more appropriate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331385/indexing-the-unordered-pairs-of-a-set)

In my opinion, the selected answer is so suboptimal that it can be considered plain wrong.

The table you are building can be indexed with N(N-1)/2 values, while the binary approach uses 2<sup>N</sup>.

With a 64 bits unsigned integer, you could encode about sqrt(2<sup>65</sup>) values, that is 6 billion names, compared with the 64 names the binary approach will allow.

Using a big number library could push the limit somewhat, but the computations involved would be hugely more costly than the simple o(N) reverse indexing algorithm needed by the alternative approach.

My conclusion is: the binary approach is grossly inefficient, unless you want to play with a handful of values, in which case hard-coding or precomputing the indexes would be just as good a solution.

Since the question is very unlikely to match a search on the subject, it is not that important anyway.