# Indexing the (unordered) pairs of a set

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is an auto-answered question, originating from [this more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326087/decoding-via-number-combinations-algorithm-in-python-3/21328523#21328523) where the OP seems to have lost interest after selecting a wrong (IMHO) answer.

I did check previous questions on the subject, but none seemed to tackle the problem.

### What use is that?

Imagine you have 4 people: Abdul, Beatrix, Charlie and Daria.
You want to store informations about the way these persons feel toward each other

```
Abdul and Beatrix are in love
Beatrix and Charlie hate each other
Abdul and Charlie are good friends
Daria and Beatrix don't know each other
etc.
```

In the terse and devoid of poetry world of computers, that could translate to:

```
relation (Abdul  , Beatrix) = love;
relation (Beatrix, Charlie) = hate;
relation (Abdul  , Charlie) = friendship;
etc.
```

In other words, if you want to map the relations between each pair of people, you will need a data structure that allows you to maintain a unique value for each pair of people.

Although there are dozens of ways of implementing a suitable data structure, you might want in some case this table to be a fixed-size array directly indexed by the pairs representing a given relation.

### Some definitions:

given I<sub>N</sub> the set of the first N natural integers, let's call P<sub>N</sub> the sequence of all unordered pairs (a,b) of I<sub>N</sub> such that a <> b, sorted in lexicographic order.

In (hopefully) less cryptic English, ***P enumerates all the possible relations between two elements of I***.

example (for N = 4):

**I<sub>4</sub>   = (0,1,2,3)

     P<sub>4</sub> = ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3))**

Note that the cardinality of P<sub>N</sub> is N(N-1)/2, so
**the most compact zero-based index of P<sub>N</sub> will be in the [0..N(N-1)/2-1] range**.

### Question:

how can we index P<sub>N</sub> in a compact and efficient way?

In other therms,

- define a function p<sub>N</sub>(a,b) that, given a pair (a,b) of elements of I<sub>N</sub>, produces a unique index of P<sub>N</sub> in the range [0..N(N-1)/2-1]
- define the reverse-indexing function p<sub>N</sub><sup>-1</sup> that, given an index of P<sub>N</sub>, will produce the corresponding (a,b) pair

The way P<sub>N</sub> is arranged is of lesser importance, but a lexicographic order would probably be the most convenient.

example:

**P<sub>4</sub> = ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3))

     p<sub>4</sub>(1,3) = 4

     p<sub>4</sub><sup>-1</sup>(4) = (1,3)**

Comment: Just a note on terminology: if such a function p<sub>N</sub> exists, you don't have a set; you have a sequence.

Comment: @chepner thanks. English is not my native language, and I could not find the proper word :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers I see here so far do the first calculation fine, but the backward calculation requires looping, which is not necessary.

Consider the following example with `n=5`, showing how the elements are numbered.

```
    0   1   2   3   4
  +---+---+---+---+---+
0 |   |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 | 0 |   |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 | 1 | 4 |   |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
3 | 2 | 5 | 7 |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
4 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 9 |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

Given a tuple `(x, y)` (assuming `x < y`), the first index in column `x` is given by

```
n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-x = (n-1 + n-x) * x / 2 = (2n - x - 1) * x / 2
```

The offset in that column is simply `y - x - 1`. This yields the total expression

```
p_n(x, y) = (2n - x - 1) * x / 2 + y-x-1 = (2n - x - 3) * x / 2 + y-1
```

---

Now, going the other way around is tricky. We have some values `p` and `n` and need to find `x` and `y`. We can make our life simpler though by assuming we're looking for the first cell in the column, i.e. `y = x+1`. If we plug this in in the formula above, we obtain

```
p = (2n - x - 1) * x / 2
```

Rewriting this formula yields

```
x^2 - (2n-1) * x + 2p = 0
```

which is a simple quadratic equation and can be solved for x:

```
x = [(2n-1) - Sqrt((2n-1)^2 - 8p)] / 2
```

Of course, we likely overestimated `x`, because we assumed the lowest possible value for `y`. However, we are not that far off (still in the right column), so rounding down the value is enough to get the real `x`.

Plugging the `x` value we found into the original formula yields a very easy equation for `y`:

```
x = Floor( [(2n-1) - Sqrt((2n-1)^2 - 8p)] / 2 )
y = p - (2n - x - 3) * x / 2 + 1
```

---

It can be argued that taking the square root of a number is a slow operation (which is true), but this approach will outperform a loop for bigger values of `n`.

Comment: We've got a winner! I was daunted by the quadratic equation, but you tamed it beautifully. I don't think the square root would be an issue, unless you were running on a 8 bits microcontroler.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be more of a math question.

If my calculations are correct then,

```
For a pair P (a,b), the number of pairs of type (a,x) [x < b] before P shall be b-a-1.

The number of pairs of type (x,y) [x < a] = (n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)...+(n-a) = a*n - a(a+1)/2

Hence total number of pairs before P = (b-a-1) + a*n - a(a+1)/2.
```

**Hence index of P = (b-a-1) + a*n - a(a+1)/2.**

For reverse indexing, first find a, because we know that for 1st n-1 terms, a = 0, for next n-2 terms, a = 1, etc.

This can be done in O(N) time by iterating over these values and seeing when it exceeds the index.

Once we find a, then b can be found from the equation above.

Comment: Right-ho, sir. A maths question that might be of some limited use for a programmer :) Anyway, we came to the same conclusion, except that you don't even need the equation to find back b. I will leave the question open for a while in case some brilliant mathematician comes up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

#### index computation

let a and b be two elements of I<sub>N</sub> **with a < b**

If we represent P as a half-filled matrix, the idea is to add an offset to the start of each row to get a contiguous numbering at the start of the next row.

Row 0 starts with an offset of 0 and contains N-1 values
Row 1 starts at N-1 and contains N-2 values
etc..

The offset value of Row `a` will be the sum of `N-i` for i in (1..a).

The final pair index will be `offset(a)+b`.

computation of offset(a) is done by using the formula that gives the sum of the first n integers: s(n) = n(n-1)/2.

Here offset(a) will be = s(N) - s(a).

After a bit of maths, the resulting formula can be written as:

**p<sub>N</sub>(a,b) = a(2N-a-3)/2 + b - 1**

The pseudo-code for P is then:

```
function p (a,b)
{
    if (a>b) swap(a,b)
    return a * (2 * N - a - 3) / 2 + b - 1
}
```

#### reverse indexing

All credit goes to Heuster for finding an elegant solution to the problem.
See the selected answer for details.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
const N1 = 2 * N - 1
const N2 = N1 * N1
function reverse_p (p)
{
    a = floor( (N1 - sqrt(N2 - 8 * p)) / 2)
    b = p - (2 * N - a - 3) * a / 2 + 1
    return (a, b)
}
```