# Mapping unordered pairs (with repetition) to index

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In a set of `C+1` integer values `{0,1,...,C}`. How to index the pairs `{00,01,...,0C, 11,12,...,1C,22,...2C,...,CC}`?. I understand that the total of pairs `ab` with `a <= b` is `(C+1)(C+2)/2` pairs. I could figure out a way of mapping pairs `ab` to their index `i` when `a <= c/2`, but the mapping won't work for the other half of the pairs.

Is there a simple expression that can map pairs `ab` to an index `i`? This question is very similar to [Indexing the (unordered) pairs of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331385/indexing-the-unordered-pairs-of-a-set), but repetition is not allowed there.

Comment: Isn't `(C+1)*a + b` the index of any pair?

Comment: That would be valid if considering the ordered pairs. The set of pairs contain only `01`, but `10` is not considered as it has `b>a`.

Comment: I see. . I have a hunch that it is `(C-1)*a + b` if you are looking for only the upper half of the pairs... Although I don't have proof for it. .

Answer (score 1):

After some math, I got an expression.

The expression is `i = a(C+1) - a(a-1)/2 + b - a`. I'll post the math behind as soon as I have some time to type on latex, but the idea is to count how many pairs were counted already with a difference of triangular sums based on `a` and `C`(first two terms), then add what is missing based on both `b` and `a`.

Comment: Purely from a geometrical standpoint, it looks like this is the answer.